# fullcalendar together with google calendar's attachments

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, attachment

I'm playing with the jquery plugin fullcalendar https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar
I'm doubting to write my own serverside calendar management system or simply use google calendar. The integration with google calendar works flawlessly but I wonder how I can get access to the google calendar events attachments (these can be enabled here https://www.google.com/calendar/render?settings=4).

I would like something like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'link/to/google/calendar',
        className: 'gcal-event'         // an option!

    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        alert(event.attachment);
        return false;
    }
});
```

So my question little more detailed: How can I have an events attachment in the event object so I can access it in the eventClick handler.

EDIT: I just checked and there is no info about attachments in the xml from the google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the attachment are not included in the google calendar's feed data since this is an experimental feature from google. So getting easy access to these attachments is impossible for now.